# Is BTREE or HASH smaller as a type for enum indexing?

Tags: mysql, optimization, size

I am tasked with optimizing a table's disk size. Let's suppose we have a table like this:

`users(id, <some other fields>, role)`

where `role` is a `varchar` of some large maximum size, but if I run

```
select distinct `role`
from users;
```

I get three values:

> admin
>
> regular
>
> guest

There are many million records involved and it's clear that due to the fact that it's a `varchar`, each record allocates character_size * length bytes.

I have suggested the idea of changing `role` into an `enum`, since it then maps numeric values to each possible value under the hood and the actual texts are stored exactly once, on table level. So far, so good.

Now, the `role` field has an `index` of `BTREE` type and I have this script planned after the column change:

```
DROP INDEX `Role` ON users;
CREATE INDEX `Role` ON users(`role`) USING BTREE;
```

My question is this: Would another type, like `HASH` save more space in this scenario than `BTREE`? Or, to put it more broadly: is there a better type for the index than `BTREE` in terms of size?

Comment: What storage engine do you use for the `users` table? If you are using InnoDB (which is the default), are you aware that InnoDB does not support hash indexes? Even if you use the "USING HASH" syntax, it ignores you and creates the index as a BTREE index.

Comment: @BillKarwin `innodb`. And the answer is no, I was not aware of that.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `enum` has some [drawbacks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types) you should be aware of. Depending on your use cases, an explicit `user_roles` table might be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB does not support HASH indexes. In MySQL 8.0, they finally created a warning so you can tell that it did not do what you asked when you request a HASH index that is not supported:

```
mysql> create table users (id serial primary key, role varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create index role on users(role) using hash;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                 |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 3502 | This storage engine does not support the HASH index algorithm, storage engine default was used instead. |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In prior versions of MySQL, it would silently accept your create table statement, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would even show that the index is a HASH index, but it's a lie. It is created as a BTREE index.

In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html it says:

[image]

There's a very thin justification for the confusing behavior of preserving the HASH index definition: if you define an index with `USING HASH` and subsequently alter the table to use the MEMORY storage engine, the index option will be supported. This is in the comments in this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22632

In my opinion, this wasn't a good justification for the amount of confusion caused by this behavior.

---

To handle a growing database, you are better off using other traditional techniques:

- Choose the smallest data type for each column that supports the values you need. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html
- Use `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`, but this might not help as much as you expect. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html
- Don't keep so much data on a single MySQL instance. Archive or delete data that is no longer needed.
- Split the data over multiple MySQL instances. This is called *sharding*. It adds complexity to your application, but you can keep growing the dataset.
- Get a larger storage volume.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Bill. I'm familiar with the techniques you have pointed to, but was not sure about this specific item I was asking about. Your answer clarified the issue. Thanks!

Comment: "In prior versions of MySQL, it would silently accept your create table statement, and SHOW CREATE TABLE would even show that the index is a HASH index, but it's a lie. It is created as a BTREE index." I agree with you that it was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an index will depend on the table engine you use. For MySQL you have InnoDB and MyISAM. MyISAM will store the index in a separate file, while InnoDB will store the index with the table data (and does not offer HASH indexes). I don't think you will want to use MyISAM though because it lacks integrity features that InnoDB has.

I don't think a HASH index is a great idea here, because you will end up with only three hash values, since the `role` column only has three possibilities. The index's cardinality will be low. With that, your option becomes BTREE.

A hash index will be one number per row (its hash number) and a pointer to a row, so I'd say two integers. An InnoDB secondary index will be a value plus a pointer to the table's clustered index, so that would be the same size. If the index is a clustered index, it will also contain the table's primary key, and it will be larger.

Comment: Can you explain what happens under the hood?

Comment: I think HASH indexes are limited to the MEMORY storage engine.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the insightful answer, I upvoted it, but will have to accept the other answer as it is more detailed.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, @Bill Karwin explaining that MySQL has been lying to us this whole time is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither index type is useful for

```
INDEX(role)
```

unless the `role` you are testing for is rare.  This is because the Optimizer will eschew an `INDEX` if it is not very selective.  Hence save space by getting rid of that useless index.

On the other hand,

```
INDEX(role, some-other-column)
```

can be very useful, regardless of the cardinality of `role`.  And it may well be worth having the index, even if it takes space.  Is it worth having?  The answer to that is determined by the queries that might use such an index.

As for BTree vs Hash -- Note that MySQL did not bother to implement Hash.  After all, Btree is about as fast as Hash, plus is useful for ranges, unlike Hash.

As far as `INT` vs `VARCHAR` vs `ENUM` when using BTree -- they all work pretty much the same.

As for space, `ENUM` takes 1 byte, it is the winner.

As for "normalization", well, an "id" can't be smaller than 1 byte.  And looking up the value takes an extra table, etc.  So, it is not very useful *for `role`*.

Don't even consider MyISAM.  It is going away.  And it is not allowed in clustering environments.

The only reason for considering the size of an index is to measure the benefit of getting rid of a *useless* index.

Comment: We need the index because of the filters, so it is rather a question of how to use less space. As about your last sentence, I believe that if there is a 1D index on A and another on B and those are filtered together, then it makes sense to drop them and create a composite index instead. It's a different scenario from the one described in the question, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @LajosArpad - many scenarios are covered here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql